# PayPal Buy Now button with amount does not show amount

Tags: paypal

I'm trying to add an `amount` to my current PayPal Buy Now form, and it doesnt show the amount. Is there an ordering of input fields that I am missing?

```
<form class="right" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post" target="_blank">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_s-xclick"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name" value="${sessionScope.paypalDescription}"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="hosted_button_id" value="YNRM27K9B4JGW"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.keeboi-gwapo.com/thankyou.d0"/>
    <input type="hidden" name="amount" value="500.00" />
    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD"/>
    <input type="image" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!"/>
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1"/>
</form>
```

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using a hosted button.  As such, you need to login to your PayPal account, go into your button manager, and edit the button accordingly.

You can't just add fields to the button code like that when using hosted buttons.  Part of the benefit of hosted buttons is that it hides those parameters from people who might try to adjust the values before triggering the PayPal payment.

Comment: `item_name` is a custom field that I added on top of the generated button content yet it works. I will try a button without `hosted_button_id`

Comment: Thanks, I've accepted this is the correct answer. How I solved it was removing the `hosted_button_id` and adding `business` with my merchant account email as the value, then changing `_s-xclick` to `_xclick`.

Answer (score 0):

All those input fields are hidden, for submission with the form. If you want to display them as well, you have to write more HTML.